# How to find kth generation of a family tree in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, family-tree

I am trying to find a list of all the family members for the `kth` generation of a given family. We are given the first members of the family and the family tree as well. Below is my KB for the same and also the implementation. I am not able to figure how I can get the `kth` generation for this family tree? Lets say `k = 4`. One way of doing it is that I can find 4 times the relation like this:

```
4thGen(X,Y) :- parent(X,A),parent(A,B),parent(B,C),parent(C,Y)
```

but this is not the correct way for this I believe.

```
male(alex).
male(romeo).
male(oscar).
male(peter).
male(bruno).
male(georg).
male(otto).
male(pascal).
male(jean).

female(lina).
female(julia).
female(rosa).
female(eva).
female(ruth).
female(silvia).
female(ida).
female(irma).
female(olga).
female(marie).
female(tina).

parent(alex,julia).
parent(alex,rosa).
parent(lina,julia).
parent(lina,rosa).
parent(romeo,peter).
parent(julia,peter).
parent(rosa,silvia).
parent(oscar,ida).
parent(eva,ida).
parent(eva,bruno).
parent(peter,bruno).
parent(peter,georg).
parent(peter,irma).
parent(ruth,georg).
parent(ruth,irma).
parent(silvia,otto).
parent(silvia,pascal).
parent(irma,olga).
parent(irma,jean).
parent(otto,olga).
parent(otto,jean).
parent(jean,tina).
parent(marie,tina).






father(X,Y):-parent(X,Y),male(X).
grandfather(X,Y):-father(X,Z),parent(Z,Y).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make more general predicates you can use recursion:

```
kthGen(X,Y,1):-parent(X,Y).
kthGen(X,Y,K) :- parent(X,A),K1 is K-1,kthGen(A,Y,K1).
```

Here are some queries:

```
?- kthGen(alex,julia,1).
true ;
false.

?- kthGen(alex,peter,2).
true ;
false.

?- kthGen(alex,bruno,2).
false.

?- kthGen(alex,bruno,3).
true ;
false.
```

Two important things to notice here:

- Firstly your graph is **directed** (e.g if `parent(A,B)` you can't have `parent(B,A)` ), this matters because if it was **undirected** you could fall into cycles (e.g  `kthGen(alex,julia,4).` would succeed due to the path `alex->julia->alex->julia` ,you could solve that by adding another list that keeps track persons you've visited).
- Secondly if you try:

  `?- kthGen(alex,bruno,K).
          ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
          ERROR: In:
          ERROR:    [8] kthGen(alex,bruno,_7630)
          ERROR:    [7] <user>`

So the predicate `kthGen/3` does not have relational behavior. You could use library CLPFD:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

kthGen(X,Y,1):-parent(X,Y).
kthGen(X,Y,K) :- parent(X,A),K1 #= K-1,kthGen(A,Y,K1).
```

Now if you try:

```
?- kthGen(alex,bruno,K).
K = 3 ;
false
```

much better !!.

---

**UPDATE**

In order to find kth generation persons from a person X you could modify accordingly:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

kthGen(Y,1,[Y]).
kthGen(X,K,[X|T]) :- parent(X,A),K1 #= K-1,kthGen(A,K1,T).
```

Example:

```
?- kthGen(alex,4,L).
L = [alex, julia, peter, bruno] ;
L = [alex, julia, peter, georg] ;
L = [alex, julia, peter, irma] ;
L = [alex, rosa, silvia, otto] ;
L = [alex, rosa, silvia, pascal] ;
false.
```

This gives all the possible 4th generations from alex. If you want to find more complex e.g 4th gen from alex or lina you could find it separately an write another predicate that concatenates the results...

---

**UPDATE 2**

In last update I keep track of all persons until 4th generation. If you want just 4th gen simply modify like:

```
kthGen(Y,1,[Y]).
kthGen(X,K,L) :- parent(X,A),K1 #= K-1,kthGen(A,K1,L).
```

Examlpe:

```
?- kthGen(alex,4,L).
L = [bruno] ;
L = [georg] ;
L = [irma] ;
L = [otto] ;
L = [pascal] ;
false.
```

Now if you want all results in one list:

```
?- findall(X,kthGen(alex,4,[X]),L).
L = [bruno, georg, irma, otto, pascal].
```

Comment: Great one! But how do I combine all these people in a single list, which at the end of the query gives me all `kth` gen members? For e.g., for k = 4, it should return `[Bruno, georg, Irma, otto, pascal]`

Comment: I was able to achieve similar result with my lineage function as well, but your way of implementation is far better than mine was. But I still couldn't figure out a way to get all people of a given generation. One way I tried to do is to run through all family members and add to list whichever satisfied my current criteria. But, this is very inefficient and I think there might be better way for that?

Comment: How is it supposed to return `[Bruno, georg, Irma, otto, pascal]` since Bruno is not parent of georg??

Comment: Bruno and georg are both 4th generation of the family tree if you consider alex and lina as first generation. Bruno and georg are coming from peter who is the 3rd in family tree generation. So, both bruno and georg will be of 4th gen. They are step brothers.

Comment: To be more specific in what query do you expect the list above? kthGen(bruno,pascal,4)??

Comment: `kthGen(alex,lina,4,L)` where alex and lina are the first generation and counting from them, we need the 4th generation to be displayed in the list `L`.

Comment: Ok I may misunderstood since in your example: `4thGen(X,Y) :- parent(X,A),parent(A,B),parent(B,C),parent(C,Y)` X,Y are X the start Y the end but now you're asking alex,lina to be the start (both 1st gen) ... I will edit accordingly but is this what you want to find: kthGen(X,Y,..) X,Y will be in same generation??

Comment: Also this diesn't make sense to me since if you want to find 4th gen from alex,lina why not just find kthGen(alex,4,L) and kthGen(lina,4,L)? which would be much simpler?

Comment: yes. X and Y would be in same generation. To make matter simple, we can assume X and Y as alex and lina respectively. One way I thought was using all the output we get from descendants(Ds,X) where Ds will contain all descendants of X. We can then pass that list to check for each entry whether it is actually the fourth generation of X or not. Does it sound efficient?

Comment: yes, kthGen(alex,4,L) would also make same sense actually.

Comment: cool! Now we just need to retrieve the last element from each of these lists and append it in L. Thanks a lot!